# JavaScript - Changing Boolean Value Using onClick on Button

Tags: javascript, html

In here, I would wanna change the value of the input box. I would wanna change the value when user clicks on the `Save` button.

For example, the default value of the input box is `False` but when user clicks on the save button, the value in the input box changes to `True`.

Need help in solving the condition logic.

```js
function change() 
{

  var change = document.getElementById("check");
  if (change.value == "false") 
  {
    document.test.savereport = "True";
    document.test.submit();
  } 
  else 
  {
    change.value = "false";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="test" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="savereport" value="False" />
</form>

<div align="center">
  <button type="button" value="false" id="check" onclick="change()" />Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you check the `.value` of the clicked `<button>` element? Note, `<button>` element is not self-closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from **removing self-closing of button tag**, replace

```
document.test.savereport = "True";
```

with

```
document.test.elements[ "savereport" ].value = "true"
```

**Demo**

```js
function change() {
  var change = document.getElementById("check");
  if (change.value == "false") {
    document.test.elements["savereport"].value = "True";
    //document.test.submit();
  } else {
    change.value = "true";
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="test" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="savereport" value="False" />
</form>

<div align="center">
  <button type="button" value="false" id="check" onclick="change()"> Save </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm rusty with the exact syntax but the following code should do

```
function change() 
{

  var change = document.getElementById("check");
  if (change.value == "1") 
  {
    change.value = false
    document.test.savereport = "True";
    document.test.submit();
  } 
  else 
  {
    change.value = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to go through all the trouble of reading values for this particular requirement.
You are reading the value, comparing it to `False`, leaving it as is if so or if `True`, you change it to `False`.
Hence essentially, you are just leaving the value to be `False` no matter what the earlier value was.

So, simply change the value in `savereport` upon click of the button.

```
<script>
function change() {
  document.getElementsByName("savereport")[0].value = 'True';
}
</script>

<form name="test" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="savereport" value="False" />
</form>

<div align="center">
  <button type="button" value="false" id="check" onclick="change()" >Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Really appreciate it, a very logical answer indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The code at Question does not set the `.value` of `<input type="text" name="savereport" value="False" />` element.

You can set the `value` of `<input type="text" name="savereport" value="false" />` element to `"false"` and evaluate boolean `false` as a string to check for equality.

```html
<form name="test" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="savereport" value="false" />
</form>

<div align="center">
  <button type="button" value="false" id="check" onclick="change()">Save</button>
  <script>
    var input = document.test.savereport;

    function change() {
      if (input.value === String(false)) {
        input.value = true;
        // document.test.submit();
      } else {
        input.value = false;
      }
      console.log(input.value);
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, your codes were well explained and understandable. Well explained, thank you so much.